# cannot load such file -- yajl-ruby (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having problem with a gem called 'indeed'. I'm creating a job application with ruby on rails and since I introduced this gem, everytime that I try to use the server Rails s I have this error message:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/indeed-0.1.2/lib/indeed.rb:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- yajl-ruby (LoadError)        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/indeed-0.1.2/lib/indeed.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler...
```

I installed yajl-ruby, but still doesn't work.

Does anybody know what can be the issue there?

Indeed.rb

```
require 'net/http'
require 'cgi'
require "uri"
require 'yajl'



class Indeed
```

Comment: Did you put it in the gemfile and then run a bundle install?

Comment: You should also put it in your Gemfile. It's not enough to install it by `gem install`.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't solve the problem:

`source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'yajl-ruby'
gem "yajl"
gem 'rails', '4.0.1'`

I put them in my Gemfile, tried "bundle install" and gem install yajl-ruby but nothing worked.

Comment: What is the output of `gem search yajl`?

Comment: What is your `ruby` version?

Comment: Sorry @mudasobwa I'm a bit newbie with RoR, how do I check that?

I went in the yajl.rb file but didn't find anything, only:

#   output = Yajl::Encoder.encode(obj[, :pretty => true, :indent => "\t", &block])`

But nothing else. Only default data

Comment: My Ruby version is 2.0.0

Comment: Just run `gem search yajl` from the command line and post an output here.

Comment: Here we go: 
`*** REMOTE GEMS ***

yajl-ruby (1.1.0 ruby x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32-60)
yajl-ruby-maglev- (1.1.0)
yajl-ruby-zenjoy (1.1.0)`

Comment: Try `gem install yajl-ruby --platform=ruby` to explicitly compile `yajl-ruby`, it might (or might not) help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like it is a version compatibility issue - for ruby 2.0.0.

See here: https://github.com/brianmario/yajl-ruby/issues/116 and follow luislavena comment.

In ruby 1.9.3 it works.

Comment: Oh ! So lucky !
So I did this: 
I uninstalled "yajl-ruby"
then typed: `gem install yajl-ruby --platform=ruby`
And everything works now !!!!! 

Thank you very much guys! You are the best !
I'm been working of this problem for 24hours !

Comment: I'm glad to see it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

Does adding the gems into your Gemfile: `gem 'yajl'` (or perhaps `gem 'yajl-ruby'`)
then run `bundle install` solve the problem ?

Comment: Could you try removing the `Gemfile.lock`, then run `bundle install` again ? A bit of the poor man's solution but sometimes it can help

Comment: No still doesn't work even without the Gemfile.lock the error message is still the same. I'm working under windows, dunno if it can change anything. 

source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'yajl-ruby'
gem "yajl"
gem 'rails', '4.0.1'

I tried "bundle install" and gem install yajl-ruby but nothing worked.